# Php trim string at a particular character

Tags: php, string

Is there a php string function to trim a string after a particular character. I had a look on the php.net site and did a google search but couldn't find anything. The only solution I could think of was explode and then grab the first part of the array but that's not the most elegant solution.

For example

```
$string = "/gallery/image?a=b";
$string = imaginary_function($string,'?');
echo $string; //echoes "/gallery/image"
```

Does anyone know of a good cheat sheet for php string manipulation functions?
Thanks

Comment: You might find [`s($str)->beforeFirst('?')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L389) or [`s($str)->beforeLast('?')`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str/blob/8fd0c608d5496d43adaa899642c1cce047e076dc/src/Str.php#L399) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Str).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$string = "/gallery/image?a=b";
list($url,$querystring) = explode('?', $string, 2);
```

Comment: Useful, because now i have the query sting in a variable so i can use it later if i need to. I'm all about minimising my code.

Answer (score 25):

Maybe something like this:

```
$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string, '?'));
```

Note that this isn't very robust (i.e. no error checking, etc), but it might help you solve your problem.

Comment: Funny, i just came up with the same solution, there seem to be a lot of different ways to approach this simple problem

Comment: Not surprising that PHP was loosely derived from Perl ;)  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it

Comment: But this will fail if '?' is not found in the string, i.e. it will result in an empty string.

Comment: Not sure, but I am guessing two function calls (`substr` and `strpos`) take more resources than a single call like `strstr` or `strtok`. Of course if its just run once per page load, who cares :)

Comment: might try http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php repetitively instead?

Comment: @nikc: yeah, I warned you it wasn't very robust ;)  
@dcneiner: Very true... I didn't realize that third argument had been added to `strstr`. That is probably a better way to go if you have 5.3 or above on your server.

Answer (score 10):

Try [`strtok`](http://php.net/strtok):

```
$token = strtok($str, '?');
```

Note that the second parameter is a list of separators and not a separator string.

Answer (score 7):

The `strstr` and `stristr` functions finds the first occurrence in a string and returns everything after it (including the search string). But it you supply `true` as the third argument, it brings back everything in front of the search string.

```
$string = strstr( $string, '?', true); # Returns /gallery/image
```

If the match is not found it returns `FALSE` so you could write an error check like this:

```
if( $path = strstr( $string, '?', true) ){
   # Do something
}
```

Comment: Be careful with `stristr`: "Returns the matched substring. If needle is not found, returns `FALSE`."

Comment: You don’t need `stristr`. `strstr` will suffice.

Comment: Thanks @Dominic and @Gumbo. Updated my answer to reflect both of your comments.

Answer (score 2):

```
function imaginary_function($string, $char) {
  $index = strpos($char, $needle);
  if ($index === false) { return $string };

  return substr($string, 0, $index);
}
```

An excellent, official list of string manipulation functions is available [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php).

Answer (score 2):

Although pure string functions may give better performance, this is not just a string; it's a URI. Therefore it makes more sense to use a function that's made to handle such data:

```
echo parse_url("/gallery/image?a=b", PHP_URL_PATH);
// Output: /gallery/image
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill for what you are trying to do, but if you want to break apart a URL into pieces, try the PHP function `parse_url`. Here's the [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

You'd then want the "path" portion of the resulting array.